# Add animation to filter items on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I created a filter gallery. I want to animate the filter items every time I click to a buttons. But my codes are not doing it properly. It animates filter items like toggle. If I click on a button first time it animates items, then If I click on another button it shows nothing. After that If I click on another button it animates again. What's wrong with my code? Experts please help me to find out the proper solution. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import suggestData from '../data/suggest-data.json';

const allCategories = ['All', ...new Set(suggestData.map(item => item.area))];

const Suggest = () => {
    const [suggestItem, setSuggestItem] = useState(suggestData);
    const [butto, setButto] = useState(allCategories);
    const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);
    const [anim, setAnim] = useState(false);
    const filter = (button) => {

        if (button === 'All') {
            setSuggestItem(suggestData);
            return;
        }

        const filteredData = suggestData.filter(item => item.area === button);
        setSuggestItem(filteredData);
    }

    const handleAnim = () => {
        setAnim(anim => !anim);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Suggest</h1>
            <div className="fil">
                <div className="fil-btns">
                    <div className="fil-btn">
                        <button className='btn'>Hello</button>
                        {
                            butto.map((cat, index) => {
                                return <button type="button" key={index} onClick={() => { filter(cat); setSelectedIndex(index); handleAnim(); }} className={"btn" + (selectedIndex === index ? " btn-active" : "")}>{cat}</button>
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="fil-items">

                    {
                        suggestItem.map((item, index) => {
                            return (
                                <div className={"fil-item" + (anim ? " fil-item-active" : "")} key={index}>
                                    <h1>{item.name}</h1>
                                    <h2>{item.category}</h2>
                                    <h3>{item.location}</h3>
                                    <h4>{item.type}</h4>
                                    <h5>{item.area}</h5>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Suggest;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `handleAnim()` function, you are simply toggling the value of `anim` state. So initially, its value is false and when you click the button for the first time, it is set to **true**. On clicking the next button, the `anim` state becomes **false** because the value of `!true` is false and hence your animation doesn't work. On next click, becomes **true** again since `!false` is true and the toggle continues again and again.

If you want to make your animations work on every click you will need to set the `anim` state value to `true` on every button click as below since you seem to depend on the value to set animations. As an alternative, I think it will do just fine if you simply add the animation directly to the enclosing div with class `.filter-item` instead of relying on states to trigger the animation since after every filter you apply, the elements will be re-rendered and the animation will happen after every re-render.

```js
const handleAnim = () => {
  setAnim(true);
}
```